# Server unable to send messages to client (java thread socket programming)

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

There are three files (the main function file, the server file, and the client file)

The main function file will be run where the presence of "-l" determines whether it will behave as a  server or a client if "-l" is not present.

The command arguments to run the server is

```
java DirectMessengerCombined -l 3000
```

The command arguments to run the client is

```
java DirectMessengerCombined 3000
```

There are four threads (one for receiving messages on client side, one for sending messages on client side, one for receiving messages on server side, one for sending messages on server side)

[Screenshot of running program (client on right, server on left)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evnQ8.png)

The problem with the screenshot is that the message "Hello client I am server" was not sent across to the client.

Code of Server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.imageio.IIOException;
//import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
public class DirectMessengerServer
{
    private static Socket socket;
    boolean KeepRunning = true;
    void ServerRun(String[] args) 
    {
        Thread ServerRecieve = new Thread () 
        {
            public void run ()
            {   
                System.out.println("Server recieve thread is now running");
                try
                {
                    System.out.println("Try block begins..");
                    int port_number1= Integer.valueOf(args[1]);
                    System.out.println("Port number is: " + port_number1);
                    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port_number1);
                    //SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(address, port_number1);
                    System.out.println( "Listening for connections on port: " + ( port_number1 ) );

                    while(KeepRunning)
                    {
                        //Reading the message from the client

                        socket = serverSocket.accept();    
                        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                        String MessageFromClient = br.readLine();
                        System.out.println("Message received from client: "+ MessageFromClient);


                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                }
            }
        };ServerRecieve.start();

          Thread ServerSend = new Thread () 
            {
                public void run ()
                {   
                    System.out.println("Server sending thread is now running");
                    try
                    {         

                        //Send the message to the server
                        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

                        //creating message to send from standard input
                        String newmessage = "";
                        try 
                        {
                            // input the message from standard input
                            BufferedReader input= new BufferedReader( 
                            new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                            String line = "";

                            line= input.readLine(); 
                                newmessage += line + " ";


                        }
                        catch ( Exception e )
                        {
                            System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
                        }
                        String sendMessage = newmessage;
                        bw.write(sendMessage + "\n");
                        bw.flush();
                        System.out.println("Message sent to client: "+sendMessage);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally
                    {

                    }
                }
            };ServerSend.start();










    }
}
```

Code of client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
public class DirectMessengerClient
{
    boolean KeepRunning = true;
    private static Socket socket;
    //static String[] arguments;
    //public static void main(String[] args)
    //{
    //  arguments = args;
    //}
    public DirectMessengerClient()
    {

        //System.out.println("test.");

    }
    public void ClientRun(String[] args)
    {

        Thread ClientSend = new Thread ()
        {
          public void run()
          {   
                System.out.println("Client sending thread is now running");

                    try
                    {
                            System.out.println("Try block begins..");
                            String port_number1= args[0];
                            System.out.println("Port number is: " + port_number1);
                            int port = Integer.valueOf(port_number1);
                            System.out.println("Listening for connections..");
                            System.out.println( "Listening on port: " + port_number1 );
                            while(KeepRunning)
                            {

                                String host = "localhost";
                                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
                                socket = new Socket(address, port);


                                //Send the message to the server
                                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

                                //creating message to send from standard input
                                String newmessage = "";
                                try 
                                {
                                    // input the message from standard input
                                    BufferedReader input= new BufferedReader( 
                                    new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                                    String line = "";

                                    line= input.readLine(); 
                                        newmessage += line + " ";


                                }
                                catch ( Exception e )
                                {
                                    System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
                                }
                                String sendMessage = newmessage;
                                bw.write(sendMessage + "\n");
                                bw.flush();
                                System.out.println("Message sent to server: "+sendMessage);
                            }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally
                    {

                    }

                    //finally
                //  {
                    //}


          }
        }; ClientSend.start();

        Thread ClientRecieve = new Thread ()
        {
          public void run()
          {  
              while(KeepRunning)
              {
                  try
                  {

                                System.out.println("Client Reieving thread is now running");
                                //Get the return message from the server
                                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                                String MessageFromServer = br.readLine();
                                System.out.println("Message received from server: " + MessageFromServer);
                                 if(MessageFromServer.equals(""))
                                 {
                                    KeepRunning=false;
                                    System.out.println("Shutting down");
                                    System.exit(0);
                                    socket.close();
                                 }
                                 if(MessageFromServer.equals(null))
                                 {
                                    KeepRunning=false;
                                    System.out.println("Shutting down");
                                    System.exit(0);
                                    socket.close();
                                 }
                                 if(MessageFromServer=="")
                                 {
                                    KeepRunning=false;
                                    System.out.println("Shutting down");
                                    System.exit(0);
                                    socket.close();
                                 }
                                 if(MessageFromServer==null)
                                 {
                                    KeepRunning=false;
                                    System.out.println("Shutting down");
                                    System.exit(0);
                                    socket.close();
                                 }
                                 if(MessageFromServer=="\n")
                                 {
                                    KeepRunning=false;
                                    System.out.println("Shutting down");
                                    System.exit(0);
                                    socket.close();
                                 }
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                  finally
                  {

                  }
              }
          }
        };ClientRecieve.start();
    }
}
```

Code of main function file:

```
public class DirectMessengerCombined
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DirectMessengerClient Client1 = new DirectMessengerClient();
        DirectMessengerServer Server1 = new DirectMessengerServer();
          for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
          {
                if(!args[0].equals("-l"))
                {
                    Client1.ClientRun(args);
                }
                switch (args[0].charAt(0))
                {
                    case '-':
                    if(args[0].equals("-l"))
                    {   
                        Server1.ServerRun(args);
                    }

                }
           i=args.length + 20;
          } 
    }

}
```

My question is how to make the server and client both able to continuously send and receive messages to each other (sending works on client side, but receiving does not work)

Comment: Your 2nd Thread on the server dies pretty early because the socket is null at that point, therefore it won't sent anything to the client. Just a hint for the beginning: before you start coding thread-based concurrency, you should read some basics regarding thread-safety of datatypes or inter-thread communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way is to separate accepting a connection and operating on a connection, which is what most servers do.

For example, you accept incoming connections on the main thread and operate on the connection in a thread pool, using an executor service:

```
    AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean();
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10;
    ServerSocket listen = new ServerSocket(11000);
    while(running.get()){
        Socket socket = listen.accept();
        pool.submit(() -> {

            try(InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream()){

               //put I/O logic here


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

In this example input and output is processed in the same thread, if you want to concurrently read and write, submit two tasks, one operating on the input, one of the output. Important: you only get your socket *after* the connection has been accepted.

If you want to thread communicate with each other, you can do this with a shared object, i.e. a message queue. But this datastructure must be *threadsafe*, and the JDK provides a lot of those datastructure:

- ConcurrentHashMap
- CopyOnWriteArrayList
- ConcurrentSkipListSet
- ...

for example

```
 final ConcurrentLinkedDeque<String> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<>();

 while(running.get()){
    Socket socket = listen.accept();
    pool.submit(() -> {

        try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))){
            while(socket.isConnected()){
                queue.push(reader.readLine());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    pool.submit(() -> {
        try(OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream()){
            if(!queue.isEmpty()){
                 os.write(queue.pop().getBytes());
            }
         } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
    });
 }
```

And basically the same for the client, except that you dont accept a connection but open one